# Eliminate duplicate values on an inner join (is it even possible given this scenario?)

Tags: t-sql, duplicates, rows

I have a query that pulls information from two different tables at a different granular level. I was wondering if it is even possible to keep the value from repeating on the right (only return one row with 110811.67 rest zero) and preserve all values on the left.

```
select x.pt_year,
       x.pt_month,
       x.pt_amount,
       y.fp_earnedprem
from
(
    select sum(a.amount) as pt_amount
         , va.ACCT_YEAR as pt_year, va.ACCT_MONTHINYEAR as pt_month, ptp.PTRANS_CODE as pt_code 
    from fact_policytransaction a
    join VDIM_ACCOUNTINGDATE va
    on a.ACCOUNTINGDATE_ID=va.ACCOUNTINGDATE_ID
    join DIM_POLICYTRANSACTIONTYPE ptp 
    on a.POLICYTRANSACTIONTYPE_ID=ptp.POLICYTRANSACTIONTYPE_ID
    group by va.ACCT_YEAR, va.ACCT_MONTHINYEAR, ptp.PTRANS_CODE    
) as x
join
(
    select sum(fp.EARNED_PREM_AMT) as fp_earnedprem
         , dm.MON_YEAR as fp_year, dm.MON_MONTHINYEAR as fp_month 
    from fact_policycoverage fp
    join dim_month dm on fp.MONTH_ID=dm.MONTH_ID
    group by dm.MON_YEAR, dm.MON_MONTHINYEAR
) as y 
 on x.pt_year  = y.fp_year
and x.pt_month = y.fp_month
where x.pt_year=2016 and x.pt_month=6
order by x.pt_year, x.pt_month

pt_year pt_month pt_amount      fp_earnedprem  
2016    6        4340.00        110811.67  
2016    6       15569.00        110811.67  
2016    6       30024.00        110811.67  

pt_year pt_month pt_amount      fp_earnedprem  
2016    6        4340.00        110811.67  
2016    6       15569.00        0   
2016    6       30024.00        0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ROW_NUMBER

```
;with cte as (
select x.pt_year,
       x.pt_month,
       x.pt_amount,
       y.fp_earnedprem
from
(
    select sum(a.amount) as pt_amount
         , va.ACCT_YEAR as pt_year, va.ACCT_MONTHINYEAR as pt_month, ptp.PTRANS_CODE as pt_code 
    from fact_policytransaction a
    join VDIM_ACCOUNTINGDATE va
    on a.ACCOUNTINGDATE_ID=va.ACCOUNTINGDATE_ID
    join DIM_POLICYTRANSACTIONTYPE ptp 
    on a.POLICYTRANSACTIONTYPE_ID=ptp.POLICYTRANSACTIONTYPE_ID
    group by va.ACCT_YEAR, va.ACCT_MONTHINYEAR, ptp.PTRANS_CODE    
) as x
join
(
    select sum(fp.EARNED_PREM_AMT) as fp_earnedprem
         , dm.MON_YEAR as fp_year, dm.MON_MONTHINYEAR as fp_month 
    from fact_policycoverage fp
    join dim_month dm on fp.MONTH_ID=dm.MONTH_ID
    group by dm.MON_YEAR, dm.MON_MONTHINYEAR
) as y 
 on x.pt_year  = y.fp_year
and x.pt_month = y.fp_month
where x.pt_year=2016 and x.pt_month=6
)
, Rn as (
select *
, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by pt_year, pt_month order by pt_year, pt_month) as RoNum
from cte
)
select pt_year, pt_month, pt_amount
, IIF(RoNum = 1, fp_enarnedprem, 0)
from Rn
order by pt_year, pt_month
```

the main part is your own query, I only added below section and a line on top and moved order by to the bottom.

```
)
, Rn as (
select *
, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by pt_year, pt_month order by pt_year, pt_month) as RoNum
from cte
)
select pt_year, pt_month, pt_amount
, IIF(RoNum = 1, fp_enarnedprem, 0)
from Rn
order by pt_year, pt_month
```

Comment: Thanks much! it does appear to not like pt_year, pt_month, pt_amount that you added at the bottom.                                                                  Getting Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Invalid column name 'pt_year'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Invalid column name 'pt_month'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Invalid column name 'pt_amount'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
Invalid column name 'RoNum'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
Invalid column name 'fp_enarnedprem'.

Comment: There was a missing part : "from Rn" I edited my answer.